# How to expand components in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

`SpringBoot 2` `Vaadin 12.0.3`

I've spent some time watching video tutorials and studying online examples of Vaadin. Unfortunately, so much has changed that options that I was hoping to try are no longer there.

- `CssLayout` is no longer there - replaced by `Div` which does not expose `expand(Component)`.
- `component.setWidth("300")` has no effect.
- `component.setWidth("300", UNIT.*)` does not work because `UNIT` is not in class path.
- `component.setWidth("300px")` works but it's far from elegant and setting explicit width on a component which displays text is far from ideal.

I have three *pseudo horizontal* menu items. On a large screen, they'd be truly horizontal. On smaller screen, I'd like them to go into vertical mode.

- Combo Box should expand to the width of the longest label.
- Text Box should expand to available real estate. (Available width - Combo Box width - Search Button width)
- Search Button should expand to the width of the Icon and Label without any wrapping.

Is this possible to achieve using Vaadin 12 Layout/Component contract or do I have to spend time defining such control in CSS file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the difference between `CssLayout` and `Div` since neither has ever had any `expand` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies that there would have been a trivial way of achieving your use case with the built-in layouts in Vaadin 7 or Vaadin 8 without using CSS. What you're describing about automatically switching between horizontal and vertical modes depending on the screen size sounds like something that would require some degree of responsive layouting, which typically implies directly using CSS.

What you could have done in older versions is to have Java logic that either uses a `VerticalLayout` or a `HorizontalLayout` depending on the situation. Those two classes are still available for the same kind of use cases. The APIs have changed to better align with the underlying flexbox functionality, but the overall functionality is still the same.

You could also look in to `FormLayout` (part of the core framework) or the `Board` layout (separate add-on) which both provide some responsive functionality. They are, however, originally intended for slightly different use cases (forms and dashboards respectively), so it might be slightly challenging to make them fit your exact requirements.